# How jQuery only apply once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following lines to add a picture before, a `span`. I use `$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {` to load this section after ajax finished.

```js
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#filter-id-1886 > span.text-title").before("<img width='35px' src='https://example.com/wp-content/themes/rasa/assets/img/01.png' alt='cheese icon' class='mr-2'>");

  });

});
```

My problem is that it adds a picture after few seconds. In fact, after 5 minutes, I see over 10 images added before the `span`, I am looking for a solution to add picture only once.

Update (to add more information):
I use ajax to load data from the database, and in this case, if I remove `$( document ).ajaxComplete(function()` the picture will not add before span. In fact, I am looking for a solution that:
Only apply function after ajax complete once.
I thought about using delay but, I am looking for a more stable solution.

Comment: It's normal because `ajaxComplete` will be called with every ajax request you make.

Comment: The code misses some important information.  The code shown in `ajaxComplete` shouldn't create a new ajax request. So it is not clear why the image is added over on over again. That would only happen if issue an `ajax` request over and over again, somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$(document).ajaxComplete`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) fires the callback *"whenever an Ajax request completes".*  So, if you wrap your ajax event in an `ajaxComplete` inside of a `$(document).ready` what will happen is:

1. Once the document is ready, your AJAX request fires
2. Once it completes, the callback to the AJAX complete is called again, which will execute automatically because the document is already ready, sooooo
3. ...another AJAX request will be fired.
4. Return to step 2

You have an infinite loop.  In order to avoid this, and not knowing anything else about your setup, I'd recommend simply removing the wrapping `ajaxComplete`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#filter-id-1886 > span.text-title").before("<img width='35px' src='https://example.com/wp-content/themes/rasa/assets/img/01.png' alt='cheese icon' class='mr-2'>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, I used `$(document).ajaxComplete` since I use filters, the filter use ajax, then when I remove `$(document).ajaxComplete`, after ajax complete the image will not add and I only see text.

Comment: I am looking for a solution that only applies function once after ajax is complete.

Comment: @M.SallarRabiei It sounds like there is perhaps additional detail missing from the question to allow the community to understand the issue.  Would it be possible to update it to include a [mcve] so readers have all the information needed?  Critically, understanding what this other AJAX call you are waiting for is, and what it is you are trying to accomplish with this script?